# how to access field names with periods?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_listings AS (
  SELECT
    listings.*,
    images.url AS "image.url"
  FROM listings
  LEFT JOIN images ON images.id = listings.image_id
)
```

When querying, I can't seem to access `view_listings.image.url` in a where clause. What is the correct way to access it?

```
SELECT *
FROM view_listings
WHERE view_listings.image.url IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is "can't seem to access" supposed to mean? Does it not show up if you `select *` from the view? Do you get an error if you try select it explicitly? Do you get the wrong values? Something else?

Comment: Avoid quoted identifiers (using `"`) they are *much* more trouble than they are worth it. Your problem is just one of many that are waiting for you.

Comment: suggestions? looking at returning everything as JSON, but that looks like even more work.

Comment: @JonathanOng maybe you should ask another question considering your issue with JSON and describe it there. :-)

Comment: latest solution: using `ROW_TO_JSON(table)` everywhere. works way better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using double quotes `" "` to name your column.

You should access it the same way - `view_listings."image.url"`.

Though, I'd really recommend using  symbol `_` as word delimiter instead and name the column `image_url` so that you won't need to deal with this and remember it all the time when calling that column in queries.

Comment: sweet! works. i swear i tried this before but it didn't work.

Comment: trying to make the JSON version very easy - i unflatten everything before i send it to the client like mongodb. i rarely query these quoted fields. i am looking at alternatives but just want to get my code running ASAP.